# LINQ query for getting only newest items

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have problem with thinking up LINQ query for getting only newest items.
Example of data what I have (left) and what I need to select (right):

```
Name  Notes DateRecorded  Name  Notes DateRecorded
Item1 A     1.1.2015      Item1 C     1.3.2015
Item1 B     1.2.2015      Item2 X     1.2.2015
Item1 C     1.3.2015
Item2 X     1.2.2015  

Class Properties
  Name As String
  Notes As String
  DateRecorded As Date
End Class
```

Comment: What do you mean by "newest" items ? Is it the items with a date recorded <= X days ? Or the X last items on your list ?

Comment: I would sort the collection based on the date and then grab the N first elements based on what you need.

Comment: By newest I mean items, that have latest DateRecorded column. So 1.3.2015 is newest for Item1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to group by `Name` and select the newest by `DateRecorded`:

```
Dim newestProps = props.GroupBy(Function(p) p.Name).
    Select(Function(grp) grp.OrderByDescending(Function(p) p.DateRecorded).First())
```

In query syntax:

```
newestProps = From p In props
              Order By p.DateRecorded Descending
              Group p By p.Name Into orderedNameGroup = Group
              Select orderedNameGroup.First()
```